# Is it possible to get the name/tag of putextra?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i would like to get the "Tag" /name (not the value) .
i sended from 1 activity :

```
intent.putExtra("CL2", "hello");
```

and on the other activity :

```
Bundle b =  getIntent().getExtras();
```

again, i want to get into a string the tagname ("CL2")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bundle.keySet()` returns all the extra keys, in receiving activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
    Log.d("TAG", "key: "+ key);  //returns "CL2"
    Log.d("TAG", "value: "+ bundle.get(key));  //returns "hello"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the Value of key

```
 String log = getIntent().getExtras().get("CL2");
```

and to get all keys use the following :

```
String log
for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
    log+= " " + key + " => " + bundle.get(key) + ";";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you.

```
for(String key : bundle.keySet()){
     Object obj = bundle.get(key);   
}
```